# Change field in row if other row has same value in different field

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm looking for a **Python-based** solution to a common task I often run into. (I know, there must be cool SQL-magic for this, but... not now.)

Given a table, we want to change the field `f2` if `oid` is the same.
(Assumed that `f2` always contains `bar` or is empty if `oid` is `42`):

| id | f1 | f2 | oid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | bar | 42 |
| 2 | foo |  | 49 |
| 3 | baz |  | 42 |

Becomes:

| id | f1 | f2 | oid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | foo | bar | 42 |
| 2 | foo |  | 49 |
| 3 | baz | bar | 42 |

I'm currently using `itertools.combinations` to avoid repeated comparison, which seems more efficient than a double `for`-loop. But for very large datasets, it still becomes unhandy... considering the Big-O-Notation.

Can the problem be solved more elegantly via pandas or numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Assumed that f2 always contains bar or is empty if oid is 42

Maybe we could use `groupby` + transform `first` as well:

```
df['f2'] = df.replace('', np.nan).groupby('oid')['f2'].transform('first').fillna('')
```

Output:

```
   id   f1   f2  oid
0   1  foo  bar   42
1   2  foo        49
2   3  baz  bar   42
```

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of would be to use `groupby` + `ffill`:

```
df['f2'] = df.replace('', np.nan).groupby('oid')['f2'].ffill()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   id   f1   f2  oid
0   1  foo  bar   42
1   2  foo  NaN   49
2   3  baz  bar   42
```